# How to save Data in HDFS from Spark specifying a user

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I would like to save a file in HDFS from Spark, I just try using the next line:

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(s"hdfs://hdp.asier.es:8020/assetgroup/$index/1-20170131")
```

But it throws the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=agomez, access=WRITE, inode="/assetgroup/1/1-20170131/_temporary/0":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

It is evident that the problem is because it tries to connect using the `user: agomez`, how can I configure to use another user with the adequate permission?

Comment: How you are submitting the Job? Are you using any scheduler?if yes, let me know which one and there will be different solution. If not, you are using command line to submit your spark job, it will take the user as the one which you used to login in to the command line. You may need to login as sparkload and submit the job .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved defining the Hadoop username in an environment variable:

```
HADOOP_USER_NAME=sparkload
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the access privileges on the HDFS directory `/assetgroup`, after logging in as the user hdfs, from the command line:

```
hdfs dfs –chmod –R 755 /assetgroup
```

or you can give the permission tou your user

```
hadoop fs -chown -R user:agomez  /assetgroup
```

Comment: What I want is to configure Spark to use the user=sparkload and not my user agomez. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: yes why not you have to give permission to your sparkload and you can set hadoop user  `HADOOP_USER_NAME=sparkload`